# Find time-parametrization given path and speed of a particle

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, vectors

Consider a particle in two dimensions with position vector $r(t)=<x(t),y(t)>$ and the shape of the path is described by a function $y(t)=f(x(t))$ (Thus $r(t)$ is a parametrization of $f$ with respect to time). Given some function $f$ and a speed $s$, how do we find the position vector $r(t)$ such that the particle moves always with constant speed $s$ given also some starting point?

For example, consider the path shape described by $y=x^2$. And suppose we have a particle following this path beginning at the origin at $t=0$, moving always with constant speed $s=1$. How do we find the parametrization $<r(t)>$?

Comment: Hint: the speed is the magnitude of $r'(t)$.

Answer (score 0):

You can derivate each component separately:

$r'(t)=<x'(t),y'(t)>$

However your example is different, you do not give x(t) and y(t), but only the shape of curve and the constraint of constant speed. This contraint is $r(t)^2=x(t)^2+y(t)^2=s^2$
using that you should be able to get the solution after some algebraic work

Answer (score 0):

According to your example

$s = d|r|/dt = 1$, and $r(t = 0) = 0$, s.t.

(1) $|r| = t$

Now, since $x^2 = y$,

$r^2 = y + y^2 $,

s.t. you get a simple equation of 2nd degree in y,

$y^2 + y - r^2 = 0$ .

Solve this equation,

(2) $y = \frac {-1 \pm \sqrt{1 + 4r^2}}{2}.$

Substituting here (1),

(3) $y = \frac {-1 \pm \sqrt{1 + 4t^2}}{2},$

and therefore,

(4) $x = \sqrt{y} = \sqrt{\frac {-1 \pm \sqrt{1 + 4t^2}}{2}} $.

Shall we make a test if everything is correct? Let's do it! For shorting formulas, let's denote the square root by S,

(5) $S = \sqrt {1 + 4t^2} $.

$r^2 = x^2 + y^2 = (-1 \pm S)/2 + (-1 \pm S)^2/4$

$ = (1/4) (-2 \pm 2S + 1 + S^2 \mp 2S)$

$
 = (1/4) (-1 + S^2).$

Well, introduce here the expression of S, and compare with (1) . It seems that everything is fine, isn't it?

Good luck !

Comment: While I appreciate the effort you have put into writing the answer, please find time to read our policy on homework like questions. Kindly do not give out the full answer to problems. Rather, you should point the OP in the right direction with enough guidance so that he/she can solve the problem on his/her own.

Comment: Dear @Prahar, I fully subscribe to this policy. Now, regretfully, I am no more active in this site and I don't offer answers, only clarifications, if required, on answers given by me in the past. As to the present question, I have no idea of what happens: was I asked to give some clarification of my answer? Best regards, Sofia

Answer (score 0):

the velocity is tangential to the curve and given by

$$\vec{v} =\frac{d\vec{r}}{dt}$$

and the position vector $\vec{r}$ is given as
$$\vec{r}=x~\hat{i}+y~\hat{j}$$

Given $y=f(x)$,
$$\vec{r}=x~\hat{i}+f(x)~\hat{j}$$

So,
$$\frac{d\vec{r}}{dt}=\frac{dx}{dt}~\hat{i}+\frac{d}{dt}f(x)~\hat{j}$$

Simplifying,
$$\vec{v}=\frac{dx}{dt}\left(~\hat{i}+\frac{d}{dx}f(x)~\hat{j}\right)$$

From here, get the components, use the constraint $|\vec{v}|=s$ and solve the ODE in $\dot{r}$ to get the $r(t)$

Comment: did you notice that the previous answer solved the problem completely? So, do you offer an alternative answer that doesn't solve the problem completely?

Comment: @Sofia I have given the generalised procedure (answer to first part of the question). Your solution answers the second part of the question.